# regex for digits between 5 and 7 which accepts spaces as well

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to implement a regex where only digits are accepted with spaces and the numbers of digits should be between 5 to 7. 
Below is the regex expression which i tried.

**^[0-9]{5,7}\s$**

But with space, its **not** working.

Below is the tested string

**12 34 56**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(\d *){4,6}\d$
```

---

```
^                  start of string
 (\d *){4,6}       4 to 6 digits with 0 to n trailing spaces
            \d     final digit
              $    end of string
```

---

**Edit:** To allow spaces also in the beginning and end of your string, you can use the following regex:

```
^( *\d *){5,7}$
```

Selects 5 to 7 groups consisting of a digit with 0 to n leading and trailing spaces.

Comment: The test string can be 12 3456  [Space at the last of the string]